# It it possible to have different arrow tips in the line head in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

For example some thing like this
[image]

Comment: Yes. `<-stealth` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add arrow tips to both ends of a line, you do something like

```
\draw [{arrow tip at start}-{arrow tip at end}] ...
```

So to have different arrow tips, just put in different arrow tip names on either side of the `-`, e.g.

```
\draw [<-stealth] ...
```

which will use the default arrow tip at the start, and the `stealth` arrow tip at the end.